# Using a variable in a self-selector LESS

Tags: less, lessphp

I cannot figure out how to create a self-selector. My best guess would be:

```
.mixin(@var) {
    &(~':nth-of-type(@{var}n)') {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But when used as

```
.el { .mixin(3); }
```

Produces

```
.el :nth-of-type(3n) { //do stuff }
```

And fails to produce the desired result.

Any help on this front is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which version of LESS you're using, but with 1.3.3, this should work

```
.mixin(@var) {
    @nthItem: ~":nth-of-type(@{var}n)";

    &@{nthItem} {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```